# Python: How to initialize a class with a list in the constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How can you initialize a class by calling a constructor with a list?

```
class ETF:
    def __init__(self, symbol, name, asset_class):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.name = name
        self.asset_class = asset_class
```

```
this_list = ['qqq','q invests', 'equity']

thisETF = ETF(this_list)
```

The code above will result in an error message because it only counts the list as one argument:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name', 'asset_class'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just unpack the list. It will then pass the list elements to the constructor instead of the list.

```py
thisETF = ETF(*this_list)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. Such a simple solution